# How to overwrite text on specific line in Batch [2nd Duplicate]

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I have already tried this:
{
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

```
    for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

    <nul set /p"=This is the line 1 !CR!"
    <nul set /p"=This is the line 2 "
```

but when I try it with my own code, I get this weird glitch.

[image: glitch]

I'm trying to get a result like this:

[image: look like]

The top left & right is supposed to represent what I want it to look, but the bottom left & right shows what I don't want. I'm too dumb to understand what is happening and how to fix it. (If you're wondering yes, this is something I want to do for my own Terminal/CLI project based off Command Prompt/Terminal

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code if you want to see it.

For the variables, what I wanted to achieve is more like an "align effect"
so that if for example, I run this on an another computer, the CPU String won't push some of the text to the right

```
@echo off

::: Important code, do not touch!
chcp 65001 >nul
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /value') do (set "Battery=%%E")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_Processor get Name /value') do (set "CPUName=%%E")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution /value') do (set "verti=%%E")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution /value') do (set "horiz=%%E")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get Capacity /value') do (set "memory=%%E")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('wmic path Win32_DiskDrive get Size /value') do (set "diskcap=%%E")

set /a kbmem=%memory:~0,-4%
set /a mbmem = kbmem/1024
set /a memory = mbmem/1024
set /a kb=%diskcap:~0,-4%
set /a mb = kb/1024
set /a gb = mb/1024
set /a gb = gb+6


:::  <nul set /p"=This is the line 1 !CR!"
::: [38;2;37;88;62m
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


<nul set /p"=┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                    ~───~.                  ,,.~────~..,                   │"
<nul set /p"=│    Monstera Terminal 1.01 UEFI                                                                   ,`  ,     "^~.       ,─'     ,,,,,      `^~.             │"
<nul set /p"=│    ───────────────────────────                                                                      ██▒╢▓@╦▄,   ─   ,"  ,▄▄█████████▓▓▓@▄▄   `─           │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                             ─`   ▄▓████▌▒╫▓▓██▄   ┐░  ,███▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████▄   \         │"
<nul set /p"=│    Dashboard                                                                             .─   ╓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▒▓████Ç    ╒██▓▓▓██▓▓██▓▓▓▓╢╢╢╢▒▒▀▀█▄  ",       │"
<nul set /p"=│    ─────────────────────────────────────────────                                       /   ╓╫╣╢╢╢╢▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▒▓███    ██╣▓██▓▓█▓▓▓▓╣╣╣╣╣╣╢╣╣╢╣▒▒%   ░       │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                       ░  ,▒╢╢╢╫╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓█▌   ▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╣╣╢╣╣╢▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╖"⌐  ░      │"
<nul set /p"=│    User: Maxzie Planteronix                                                           ,`  ▄▓▓╣╣╫╣▓▒╢╣╢▓▓▓▓▓▓█████▓  ]▓▓▓▓▓▓╢╣╢╢╣╣╣╢╢╢╢╢╢╢╣╢▓╣@╢╣▒▒┐  \    │"
<nul set /p"=│    Date: 10/3/2023 at 6:40 PM                                                        /   █▓▓▓▓▓▀`      ╙╙▓▓▓▓▓███▌@@▓╢╣╣▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╣▒╢▒ÑÑÑÑ╩╨╜╙▀▀▓▓▓▓▓Ç  ░   │"
<nul set /p"=│    Updates: Please wait for the owner to update the system.                        ░   g▓█▀▀╙   ,,╓⌂⌂,µ,,,▄▄▓▓▓▓██╣▒█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╣@p▄,                  ,`   │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                    ░  ╙╙  ,╥H╬▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀▀╣████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄g,   ",   │"
<nul set /p"=│    CPU: %CPUName%                                    ─  ╓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████████╫██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓██████████▌µ  \  │"
<nul set /p"=│    Resolution: %horiz%x%verti%                                                              g╢▒▒▒╢╫▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╢▓▀█▓▓▓▓▓▓▌╙╙▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀██▓▓▓▓███▄  ░ │"
<nul set /p"=│    Memory: 8GB (1 out of 4 slots are used.)                                        ⌐  ▓▓╣▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▀▀▀╙  ,▐▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▄g ╙▀▀▓▓▓╣╣╣╢╢╢▓▓▓▓███  ░ │"
<nul set /p"=│    Storage: 12.5GB of 128GB                                                        ⌐  ▓▓▓▓╣▓▓▓▓██▀▀`   ╓@╬╣╢▓▓▓██▓▒███████▓▓▓▓▓╢╢▓▓▓▄▄,   ╙╙╝▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓  ] │"
<nul set /p"=│    Graphics:                                                                       ▒  ▓▓▓▓▓██▀▀    ,╥@╣╢▓▓▓████▓██████████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▄▄▒▒╢▓▓▓▓▄,   ╙Ñ╖ ╙╫▓  ] │"
<nul set /p"=│    Manufacturer: Amiercan Metagrands Inc.                                          ░  ▓▓▓██▀    ,φ▓╣╫▓▓▓████▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓▓████▀╙▀▀█▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓╢▓▓▓█▄    ╚, ▒  ░ │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                    ░  ▓▓█"    ,▒▒╢╫▓▓▓███▓▓▓▀▀╙╩▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▌µ   \r  ░ │"
<nul set /p"=│    ─────────────────────────────────────────────                                   ▒  ▓▀     ╥▒▒╫▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀    ▄▓██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▀▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓██▄    ,  │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                    ░  `    ╓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀    ,▓▓██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓██▄  \  │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                     ───  ,╣▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀¬   ,▄▓▓█▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▓▓╣▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓U j  │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                       ░  ╠╣▒▒╫▓▓▓▓▓█▀╘    ▄█▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓▌▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓██▌,   ▀╣▒╢╢╣▓▓▓▓▓▓  ┌  │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                        ,  ▐▒▒▓╢▓▓▓█'    ,▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌   ▀▓▓▓██▓▓███µ  "╣▒▒▒╢╣╢╢▓╩  ░  │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                            ▓╣╢▓▓▓▌     ╔█▓▓▓╣▒╢▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ╙▓▓▓██▓▓██▌   ╙⌐"╙▒▒▒╜  /   │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                         ░  ╚▓╫▓▓█     á▓▓▓▓▒▒▓▀  ▓▓▌▓▓▓▓▓▌      ╟▓▓▓██▓███▄  "╖  ▒`  ░    │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                          \  ▐▓▓█     ╓▓▓▓╣▒▒▓`   ▓▓▌█▓▓▓▓█▌      ╙▒▓▓▓█▓▓██µ  "▒╜   ░     │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                           ,  ▀▓Ü    ┌▓▓▓╣╣╢▓    ▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓███▄     ╙▒╫▓▓▓▓▓██   "  ,`      │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                            \  ▐     ▓▓▓▒╣╢▓▌   ▐▓╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████▌     ║▒▓▓▓▓▓▓█  ¡──'`       │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                            ░  ┘    ╚▓▓╣╣╣╢▓   ▐▓▓╣╢▓▓█▓▓▓▓█████Ç    ▒╫▓▓▓▓▓╜  ░           │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                             "───`\   ╙╩▄▒╣▓  ╔▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓█████    ]▒▓▓▓╙  ,"            │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                    '~   ╙▀▓▓╖╫▓▓▓▓▓█▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓████    ▓▓▓   ┌'              │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                    '─.   ╙╩▓▓▓▓███▓╣▓▓▓▓▓▓█▀`    ▀   ─'                   │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                        "~.   ▀▓███▒▒▓▓▓▀╙    ─└....─'                     │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                          '^,  ▀██▒▒╜   .─``                               │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                              \  ▀▀   .─                                   │"
<nul set /p"=│                                                                                                               ░....─'                                     │"
<nul set /p"=└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘"
pause >nul
cls
wow.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "_LF=<<con: <nul  & echo\"
%__AppDir__%chcp.com 65001 1>nul
set "_wmic=%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe"

for %%i in (
     Battery,Graphics,CPUName,DiskCap,Resolution,Lines,User,spc)do if "%%~i" == "spc" (
     set "_%%~i=" <nul & for /L %%L in (01 01 77)do set "_%%~i=!_%%~i! ")else set "%%~i=" <nul
     
for /f tokens^=2^delims^=:^  %%G in ('
     %__AppDir__%mode.com con: ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe ".*s:"')do if "!_lines!" == "" (
         set "_lines=%%~G")else if !_lines!%%~G neq 16084 %__AppDir__%mode.com con: cols=160 lines=84

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution^,CurrentHorizontalResolution /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"
    `)do if Not Defined Resolution (set "Resolution=%%~i")else set "Resolution=!Resolution!x%%~i!_spc!"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "Battery=%%~i"
     
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_VideoController get Name /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "Graphics=%%~i!_spc!"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_PhysicalMemory get Capacity /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "Memory=%%~i"
     
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_Processor get Name /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "CPUName=%%~i!_spc!"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_DiskDrive get Size /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "DiskCap=%%~i"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! OS Get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "_dt=%%~i"

set "User=%UserName%!_spc!"
set "Date_Time=!_dt:~6,2!/!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~0,4! at !_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2!!_spc!"

for %%i in (kbmem,mbmem,mb,gb)do set "%%~i=" <nul
set /a "kbmem=%Memory:~0,-4%, kb=%DiskCap:~0,-4%"
set /a "mbmem=kbmem/1024, mb=kb/1024"
set /a "Memory=mbmem/1024, gb=mb/102"
set /a "gb=gb+6"

echo\ & <nul set /p "'=┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                    ~───~.                  ,,.~────~..,                   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Monstera Terminal 1.01 UEFI                                                                   ,`  ,     "^^^^~.       ,─'     ,,,,,      `^^^^~.             │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    ───────────────────────────                                                                      ██▒╢▓@╦▄,   ─   ,"  ,▄▄█████████▓▓▓@▄▄   `─           │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                             ─`   ▄▓████▌▒╫▓▓██▄   ┐░  ,███▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████▄   \         │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Dashboard                                                                             .─   ╓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▒▓████Ç    ╒██▓▓▓██▓▓██▓▓▓▓╢╢╢╢▒▒▀▀█▄  ",       │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    ─────────────────────────────────────────────                                       /   ╓╫╣╢╢╢╢▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▒▓███    ██╣▓██▓▓█▓▓▓▓╣╣╣╣╣╣╢╣╣╢╣▒▒%%   ░       │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                       ░  ,▒╢╢╢╫╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓█▌   ▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╣╣╢╣╣╢▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╖"⌐  ░      │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    User: !User:~0,77!,`  ▄▓▓╣╣╫╣▓▒╢╣╢▓▓▓▓▓▓█████▓  ]▓▓▓▓▓▓╢╣╢╢╣╣╣╢╢╢╢╢╢╢╣╢▓╣@╢╣▒▒┐  \    │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Date: !Date_Time:~0,76!/   █▓▓▓▓▓▀`      ╙╙▓▓▓▓▓███▌@@▓╢╣╣▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╣▒╢▒ÑÑÑÑ╩╨╜╙▀▀▓▓▓▓▓Ç  ░   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Updates: Please wait for the owner to update the system.                        ░   g▓█▀▀╙   ,,╓⌂⌂,µ,,,▄▄▓▓▓▓██╣▒█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╣@p▄,                  ,`   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                    ░  ╙╙  ,╥H╬▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀▀╣████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄g,   ",   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    CPU: !CPUName:~0,77!─ ╓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███████████╫██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓██████████▌µ  \  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Resolution: !Resolution:~0,71!g╢▒▒▒╢╫▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╢▓▀█▓▓▓▓▓▓▌╙╙▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀██▓▓▓▓███▄  ░ │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Memory: 8GB (1 out of 4 slots are used.)                                        ⌐  ▓▓╣▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▀▀▀╙  ,▐▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▄g ╙▀▀▓▓▓╣╣╣╢╢╢▓▓▓▓███  ░ │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Storage: 12.5GB of 128GB                                                        ⌐  ▓▓▓▓╣▓▓▓▓██▀▀`   ╓@╬╣╢▓▓▓██▓▒███████▓▓▓▓▓╢╢▓▓▓▄▄,   ╙╙╝▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓  ] │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Graphics: !Graphics:~0,70!▒  ▓▓▓▓▓██▀▀    ,╥@╣╢▓▓▓████▓██████████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▄▄▒▒╢▓▓▓▓▄,   ╙Ñ╖ ╙╫▓  ] │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    Manufacturer: Amiercan Metagrands Inc.                                          ░  ▓▓▓██▀    ,φ▓╣╫▓▓▓████▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓▓████▀╙▀▀█▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓╢▓▓▓█▄    ╚, ▒  ░ │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                    ░  ▓▓█"    ,▒▒╢╫▓▓▓███▓▓▓▀▀╙╩▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▌µ   \r  ░ │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│    ─────────────────────────────────────────────                                   ▒  ▓▀     ╥▒▒╫▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀    ▄▓██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▀▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓██▄    ,  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                    ░  `    ╓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀    ,▓▓██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓██▄  \  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                     ───  ,╣▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀¬   ,▄▓▓█▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓██▄    ╙▓▓╣▓▓▓▓██▓▓▓▓U j  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                       ░  ╠╣▒▒╫▓▓▓▓▓█▀╘    ▄█▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓▌▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓███▓▓██▌,   ▀╣▒╢╢╣▓▓▓▓▓▓  ┌  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                        ,  ▐▒▒▓╢▓▓▓█'    ,▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌   ▀▓▓▓██▓▓███µ  "╣▒▒▒╢╣╢╢▓╩  ░  │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                            ▓╣╢▓▓▓▌     ╔█▓▓▓╣▒╢▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ╙▓▓▓██▓▓██▌   ╙⌐"╙▒▒▒╜  /   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                         ░  ╚▓╫▓▓█     á▓▓▓▓▒▒▓▀  ▓▓▌▓▓▓▓▓▌      ╟▓▓▓██▓███▄  "╖  ▒`  ░    │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                          \  ▐▓▓█     ╓▓▓▓╣▒▒▓`   ▓▓▌█▓▓▓▓█▌      ╙▒▓▓▓█▓▓██µ  "▒╜   ░     │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                           ,  ▀▓Ü    ┌▓▓▓╣╣╢▓    ▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓███▄     ╙▒╫▓▓▓▓▓██   "  ,`      │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                            \  ▐     ▓▓▓▒╣╢▓▌   ▐▓╣▓▓▓▓▓▓▓████▌     ║▒▓▓▓▓▓▓█  ¡──'`       │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                            ░  ┘    ╚▓▓╣╣╣╢▓   ▐▓▓╣╢▓▓█▓▓▓▓█████Ç    ▒╫▓▓▓▓▓╜  ░           │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                             "───`\   ╙╩▄▒╣▓  ╔▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓▓▓▓▓█████    ]▒▓▓▓╙  ,"            │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                    '~   ╙▀▓▓╖╫▓▓▓▓▓█▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓████    ▓▓▓   ┌'              │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                    '─.   ╙╩▓▓▓▓███▓╣▓▓▓▓▓▓█▀`    ▀   ─'                   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                        "~.   ▀▓███▒▒▓▓▓▀╙    ─└....─'                     │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                          '^^,  ▀██▒▒╜   .─``                               │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                              \  ▀▀   .─                                   │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=│                                                                                                               ░....─'                                     │" !_LF!
echo\ & <nul set /p "'=└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘" !_LF!

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1 | echo\ & endlocal & cls & call wow.cmd
```

---

**1.** Use **[`mode columns,lines`](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)** to define the number of columns and lines you will use to fit your text on window/screen:

```bath
%__AppDir__%mode.com con: cols=160 lines=40
```

**Obs.1** Some adjustment may be necessary when changing computers, because some type of font and/or size/body setting may interfere with the dimensions.

---

**2.** Find out the total length of the longest line, and precisely between the space your variable/text will receive editing with values ​​(lengths) different values ​​for the same variable.

[image]

[image]

**Obs.2** When defining the line length, consider some space before or after when defining the variable and/or when positioning your characters on the line in the screen drawing

---

**3.** Create a variable and fill in spaces from beginning to end in a total length equal to the largest line on your "screen"

```bath
for /L %%L i (1 1 77)do set "_spc=!_spc! "
```

**4.** Concatenate the variables obtained in their relevant commands, with the variable composed of spaces

```bath
for /L %%L in (01 01 77)do set "_spc=!_spc! "

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution^,CurrentHorizontalResolution /format:xml^|find "VALUE"
    `)do if "!Resolution!" == "" (set "Resolution=%%~i")else set "Resolution=!Resolution!x%%~i!_spc!"

...
     
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_VideoController get Name /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "Graphics=%%~i!_spc!"

...
     
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! path Win32_Processor get Name /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "CPUName=%%~i!_spc!"

...

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     !_wmic! OS Get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do set "_dt=%%~i"

set "User=%UserName%!_spc!
set "Date_Time=!_dt:~6,2!/!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~0,4! at !_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2!!_spc!"
```

**5.** Finally to display, just limit the length of the variable to the limit of the corresponding line, and I did the following lines to exemplify

```bath
Line: Variable             Length       %Variable:~From,To-Length% 
User: %User%                77              %User:~0,77%
Date: %Date_Time%           76         %Date_Time:~0,76%
CPU: %CPUName%              77           %CPUName:~0,77%
Resolution: %Resolution%    71        %Resolution:~0,71%
Graphics: %Graphics%        70          %Graphics:~0,70%
```

**Obs.3:**
Avoid using escaped characters in your drawing, especially `^`, and `%`, part of his problem was the presence of these characters without the use of escape, even composing in `set /p` command...

---

**Obs:4** **[`Set /p`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)** keeps the line where the command is executing, without a "line break", it keeps itself and executes the other commands, which also keeps it on the same line... `echo\` solves your biggest problem..

---

[image]

Comment: This perfectly fixes my bug, but I have noticed something else.

When you resize the display, the top part gets cut off

Comment: Are you running this bat more than once on the same screen/instance? Would it be this?

Comment: No, It's only run once.